# Getting the average value of multiple input-type range sliders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, range

I have a div with 5 input-type range silders and a submit button.

```
<div class="sliders" id="sliderbox">
<input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="100">
<input type="range" name="points1" min="0" max="100">
<input type="range" name="points2" min="0" max="100">
<input type="range" name="points3" min="0" max="100">
<input type="range" name="points4" min="0" max="100">
<input type="submit">
</div>
```

Under this div, I have four other hidden divs that contain content.

```
<div id="hidden1">Content</div>
<div id="hidden2">Content</div>
<div id="hidden3">Content</div>
<div id="hidden4">Content</div>
```

How can I get the average combined value (a number between 0 & 100) of all the rangesliders, and then slidetoggle one of these hidden divs on submit?

For example, if the cumulative average value of these sliders is between 0 to 25 on submit, is it possible for me to display "hidden1"? Or if the value is between 25 to 50, "hidden2" and so on?

Comment: Have you coded something in jquery or javascript? If you did, put it in the question too.

Comment: No, nothing yet.

Comment: You can do: `v = ((v1+v2+v3+v4+v5) / 5 ); index = (ceil(v * 4 / 100) || 1) - 1` - See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I put in place some javascript. Probably this is something you want.

```
  let avg = 0;

  document.querySelector('.submit').addEventListener('click', event => {

    document.querySelectorAll('.range').forEach(item => {
      avg = Number(item.value) + avg;
    });

    avg = avg / 5;

    if (avg >= 0 && avg <= 25) {
      avg = 0;  

      document.querySelector('#hidden1').classList.add('show');
      document.querySelector('#hidden1').classList.remove('hide');
    }

  });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bd16ouq3/18/)

Comment: This works very, very well! I have been tinkering a bit with it, and have been wondering how I could modify it, to simply make it add the cumulative value of all the sliders to a total sum (so no averaging, but simply +'ing all the input values), which I could then display the content based on? Any ideas?

I don't know why you were downvoted by the way. This is the best solution, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 5 sliders all having the same MAX value of `100`. So max `500`
To get Element index from the current range value:

> *`Floor(current * endMax / (startMax + 1))`*

**Example**

```js
const $sliders = $("#sliderbox").find("input[type='range']");
const $cont = $(".cont");
const totSliders = $sliders.length; // 5
const startMax = totSliders * parseInt($sliders.prop("max"), 10); // 500
const endMax = $cont.length; // 4

$sliders.on("input", function() {

  // Get accumulated value of 5 sliders: 0...500
  const current = $sliders.get().reduce((ac, el) => ac + parseInt(el.value, 10), 0);
  // Get index 0...3
  const index = Math.floor(current * endMax / (startMax + 1));
  $cont.addClass("hide").eq( index ).removeClass("hide");
  console.clear(); console.log('Current:' + current + ' Index:'+ index);

}).trigger("input"); // To make immediate effect
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="sliders" id="sliderbox">
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input type="range" name="points1" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input type="range" name="points2" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input type="range" name="points3" min="0" max="100" value="0">
  <input type="range" name="points4" min="0" max="100" value="0">
</div>

<div class="cont hide" id="hidden1">1 Content</div>
<div class="cont hide" id="hidden2">2 Content!!!</div>
<div class="cont hide" id="hidden3">3 Content</div>
<div class="cont hide" id="hidden4">4 Content!!!</div>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using plain Javascript: if you utilize [HTMLNode].children, this will give you an array of elements within that node.

So you can gather all your inputs with:

```
document.getElementById('sliderbox').children
```

This will give you an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), that you can then iterate through with a for loop to retrieve each item's value, and calculate the average from that.